# How to calculate battery charging voltage

Tags: battery-charging

I have a battery with 80V and 700Ah. Please tell me is their any method to calculate charging voltage to charge this battery. Please need your help.

Comment: Maybe your question can be answered. But we will need more information. What kind of battery is it? Also, please post a picture of any text on the battery and tell us where it came from and what it is used for. It seems strange that you have such a battery, but are unable to find information about charging it from the supplier.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to determine your battery charging voltage is to look at the battery. If it has some identifying marks on it, then look those those up to find the manufacturer's charging data online, and use those figures.

If it doesn't, you could try posting a picture to see whether anybody can identify it, or guess the chemistry.

As a tip, a good way to trash a battery is to charge it without knowing anything about the battery chemistry or the charging limits.